# Ember select - Select event is getting called on page load well

Tags: javascript, ember.js, event-handling, dom-events, ember-select

Please look at this fiddle. http://jsbin.com/ofONeQ/99/edit

I am using EmberJs select control and have added a select event to the control. Problem is as the page loads for the first time, system fires the select event. What I want is to system to wait for user to change the value in the control and then only system should fire this event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you are using two different properties `selectedName` and `selectedNames`.At the beginning it was undefined on load set to 1. :)
check now

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectedName: '1',
  names: ['1','2'],
  // this observer must work when selection changes
  nameSelected: function() {

    alert('topics selection changed!');
  }.observes('selectedName')
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ofONeQ/100/edit

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. How can I get the value which user selected within `nameSelected` function ? So if user selected `1`, i should know which value user selected and based on that I can write my logic.

Comment: you can get the value by `this.get('selectedName')` inside `nameSelected` method/obeserver

Comment: This is great. I spent more than 10 hours to make this thing work :(

Comment: haha :) ...people are always available here, or tag in twitter with the question for faster response..

Comment: How can I `tag in twitter` ? Usually I get response really fast on this site. But for EmberJs I guess community is not that big

Comment: you just add `#emberjs` with the link to SO question...but still emberjs is evolving...few of us are always available here..but you can also follow discuss.emberjs.com ..there are some good discussions happen there...